# Disabling CSRF protection doesn't work for POST route

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have the following route in my Laravel app:

```
Route::post('/register-direct', 'Auth\RegisterController@direct')->name('register.direct');
```

The client wants to submit a form directly from a Wordpress landing page to Laravel, so I disabled CSRF protection for this route in the relevant middleware:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'register-direct'
    ];
}
```

However, when I try submitting the form to this route (from the Wordpress site) I get a redirect to the login page and a 419 error. This would indicate that CSRF protection is still in place for this route.

Currently, the method in question doesn't do anything:

```
public function direct(Request $request) {
    logger()->info($request->all());
}
```

The logs are not showing this message, so the problem definitely occurs before the request reaches the destination.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Put this route outside of auth middleware protection, you are redirected to login because you are not loggedIn user. so keep this method out side of the auth middleware group

Comment: It's outside of all groups.

Comment: Is there a `$this->middleware()` call in the controller's constructor?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but it is only the `guest()` middleware.

Comment: Since you're redirected to the login page it's seems like the auth middleware is running. Try logging something in `App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle` to confirm.

Comment: I'm no longer going to the login page, I'm now getting an error saying `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.` No code changed. I honestly have no idea what's going on now. The route is definitely a POST route. Maybe there is a redirect to GET for...some reason?

Comment: You might have an earlier route that matches. But if it redirects to a GET request you should see that. What's the GET URL it redirects to?

Comment: It redirects to the same URL of the POST route, except as GET (`/register-direct`).

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way and retry:

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * Indicates whether the XSRF-TOKEN cookie should be set on the response.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $addHttpCookie = true;

    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'register-direct/*'
    ];
}
```

Comment: This doesn't make a difference. Maybe some other middleware is causing the problem? Is there a way to tell?

Comment: @jovan, are you sure its a csrf issue and not CORS?

Comment: No idea what's going on anymore. Now I'm getting an error saying `The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST` even though I'm sending a POST request. This happens even if I send the request from Postman, not from the Wordpress form.

Comment: If it is CORS, what would be a good way to test and resolve this?

Comment: @jovan, Make sure on your wordpress end of things that the form is being sent as POST, or show us that part to see if theres something wrong with it